# Select only the second child of an element with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have something like this:

```
<div id="someID">
   <div class="text">
     -----other html tags
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      -----other html tags
   </div>
   <div class="text">
     -----other html tags
   </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS for the text div. It is possible to set different CSS for the second div with the class of text?

Comment: Are all the children of `#someID` going to have that same class?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: Just be aware nth child is not supported by all browsers. Your best bet is to assign unique classes/ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do with with nth-child:

```
#someID .text:nth-child(2) {
 background:red;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P6FKf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo selector nth-child i.e `div.text:nth-child(2)`